# Prometheus get last value recorded for metric

Tags: prometheus

*I'm not sure if it's possible, i'd be happy know if it's the case, but:*

Let's say I have a metric, that was last seen 14 days ago. How can I query prometheus for the last value over a specific range (i.e. 30 days) and what was its date??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since 2.2.0(March 2021) prometheus release, 'last_over_time' allows you to retrieve exactly what you need:

`last_over_time(my_metric[14d])`

Docs: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are looking to obtain the raw metrics which Prometheus has in it's store from a range of time. [extracting raw samples from prometheus](https://www.robustperception.io/extracting-raw-samples-from-prometheus).

Comment: Wow! Exactly! 
Thanks so much